# What is the best way to run two Sitecore instances off of one Solr installation?

Tags: solr, sitecore, solr4, sitecore7, sitecore7.5

In our DEV/QA environment we would like to run two different Sitecore 7.5 instances and use a single Solr 4.7.2 instance for the search.  Is it possible to do that?  Would I just set up 2 different cores in Solr?  I don't know a whole lot about Solr.  I am able to get it working for a single Sitecore installation.  Just wasn't sure if there were any gotchas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two different cores are deffinitely the easiest way of handling this.
No big issues in that

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't sure if it was better to create 2 cores or just rename the indexes for one of the installations and have all 6 indexes in one core.